# Why are SVMs / Softmax classifiers considered linear while neural networks are non-linear?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, activation-functions, support-vector-machine, softmax

My understanding is that neural networks are definitely not linear classifiers, as the point of functions like ReLU is to introduce non-linearity.

However, here's where my understanding starts to break down. A classifier, like Softmax or SVM is considered to be a "linear classifier". I'm using the definitions from [CS 231N](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/). There may be another definition of an SVM, but I'm not considering that.

In a linear classifier we have the following: $W \cdot x$ where

- $W$ is the weights
- $x$ is the input vector.

The output is a vector of scores. 1 score per label.

An SVM classifier uses hinge loss to update the weights:

[image]

A softmax classifier normalizes the output values using the softmax function and then uses cross-entropy loss to update the weights:

[image]

From the lecture [CS231n Winter 2016: Lecture 2: Data-driven approach, kNN, Linear Classification 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8inugqHkfvE&list=PLkt2uSq6rBVctENoVBg1TpCC7OQi31AlC&index=3), we have the following image to help visualize what a linear classifier does:

[image: Image about linear classifiers]

Essentially, each image can be considered a point in 3072 dimensional space, and we are drawing lines through this space. On one side of the "car" line, the car score for a given point will go up. On the other side of the "car" line, the car score for a given point will go down.

However, this doesn't seem to be that much different from ReLU (Taken from this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158549/why-are-activation-functions-needed-in-neural-networks):

[image]

So what is the fundamental difference between a "linear" classifier like Softmax / SVM and a multi-layer neural network? Why can't a SVM classifier learn any function but a neural network can?

Comment: In my view neural nets are more universal than SVMs: they can approximate any functions from one multi-dimensional space to another. They are often used as classifiers by adding SoftMax or some other trick. SVMs, on the other hand, are purely classifiers, but they can do non-linear classification using so called "kernel trick" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine).

Comment: @blamocur Ideally, our site is not meant to share "views" or "opinions" but facts and evidence. Just because there's a lot of hype around NNs now, it doesn't mean that they are more universal than SVMs, whatever that means. See also [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12239/2444).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused because the images look similar even though in reality the problems the 2 images are solving are completely different:

- The first image shows a linear classifier assigning scores for each of $C$ classes to an input image
- The second image shows a **binary classifier** (I think) scoring an item as ether white or purple (or something like that)

Consider a *single* class in the linear classifier. The linear classifier can *only* draw a *single line* through $N$ dimensional space. Items on one side of this line have negative car scores. Items on the other side have positive car scores.

For example:
[image]

Here, the 2nd image in the row represents the SVM's attempt to extract all the features of a car into a single image. As images are "closer" to this image, the SVM will give them a higher car score. As images are farther away from this image, the SVM will give them a lower car score.

The SVM cannot extract individual features, it has to smush them all into a single line in $D$ dimensional space (where $D$ is the number of pixels). That line can be represented as:

[image]

On the other hand. A multi-layer neural network, for example:
[image]

Can now partition the space into a 100 different ways. The example is a bit convoluted,  since the neural net is classifying 1 thing into several buckets instead of doing binary classification, but the principle is the same. Maybe 10 out of a 100 neurons in the second layer are dedicated to partitioning the space of images with regard to cars.